# React-native: How to change the audio speed in expo-av

Tags: react-native, audio, expo-av

I'm having trouble changing the prop: 'rate' to change the speed of the audio being played.

I'm using expo-av (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/av/).

Here's my code:

```
import {Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native'
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';
import { DataProvider } from 'recyclerlistview';
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';
import { play, pause, resume, playNext } from "../misc/AudioController";

export const AudioContext = createContext()
export class AudioProvider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      audioFiles: [],
      permissionError: false,
      dataProvider: new DataProvider((r1, r2) => r1 !== r2),
      playbackObj: null,
      soundObj: null,
      currentAudio: {},
      isPlaying: false,
      currentAudioIndex: null,
      playbackPosition: null,
      playbackDuration: null,
      rate: 2.0,
    };
    this.totalAudioCount = 0;
  }

  permissionAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert("Permission Required", "This app needs to read audio files", [
      { text: "I am ready", onPress: () => this.getPermission() },
      {
        text: "cancel",
        onPress: () => this.permissionAlert(),
      },
    ]);
  };

  getAudioFiles = async () => {
    const { dataProvider, audioFiles } = this.state;
    let media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType: "audio",
    });
    media = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      mediaType: "audio",
      first: media.totalCount,
    });

    this.totalAudioCount = media.totalCount;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      dataProvider: dataProvider.cloneWithRows([
        ...audioFiles,
        ...media.assets,
      ]),
      audioFiles: [...audioFiles, ...media.assets],
    });
  };

  loadPreviousAudio = async () => {
    let previousAudio = await AsyncStorageLib.getItem("previousAudio");
    let currentAudio;
    let currentAudioIndex;

    if (previousAudio === null) {
      currentAudio = this.state.audioFiles[0];
      currentAudioIndex = 0;
    } else {
      previousAudio = JSON.parse(previousAudio);
      currentAudio = previousAudio.audio;
      currentAudioIndex = previousAudio.index;
    }
    this.setState({ ...this.state, currentAudio, currentAudio });
  };

  getPermission = async () => {
    //    {
    //    "canAskAgain": true,
    //    "expires": "never",
    //    "granted": false,
    //    "status": "undetermined",
    //    }
    const permission = await MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync();
    if (permission.granted) {
      this.getAudioFiles();
    }
    if (!permission.canAskAgain && !permission.granted) {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, permissionError: true });
    }

    if (!permission.granted && permission.canAskAgain) {
      const { status, canAskAgain } =
        await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === "denied" && canAskAgain) {
        this.permissionAlert();
      }

      if (status === "granted") {
        this.getAudioFiles();
      }

      if (status === "denied" && !canAskAgain) {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, permissionError: true });
      }
    }
  };

  
  onPlaybackStatusUpdate = async (playbackStatus) => {
    console.log("hier");
    if (playbackStatus.isLoaded && playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
      this.updateState(this, {
        playbackPosition: playbackStatus.positionMillis,
        playbackDuration: playbackStatus.durationMillis,
      });
    }

    if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
      const nextAudioIndex = this.state.currentAudioIndex + 1;
      if (nextAudioIndex >= this.totalAudioCount) {
        this.state.playbackObj.unloadAsync();
        this.updateState(this, {
          soundObj: null,
          currentAudio: this.state.audioFiles[0],
          isPlaying: false,
          currentAudioIndex: 0,
          playbackPosition: null,
          playbackDuration: null,
        });
      }
      const audio = this.state.audioFiles[nextAudioIndex];

      const status = await playNext(this.state.playbackObj, audio.uri);
      this.updateState(this, {
        soundObj: status,
        currentAudio: audio,
        isPlaying: true,
        currentAudioIndex: nextAudioIndex,
      });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPermission();
    if (this.state.playbackObj === null) {
      this.setState({ ...this.state, playbackObj: new Audio.Sound(), });
    }
  }

  updateState = (prevState, newState = {}) => {
    this.setState({ ...prevState, ...newState });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      audioFiles,
      dataProvider,
      permissionError,
      playbackObj,
      soundObj,
      currentAudio,
      isPlaying,
      currentAudioIndex,
      playbackPosition,
      playbackDuration,
      rate,
    } = this.state;
    if (permissionError)
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <Text>It looks like you haven't accepted the permission</Text>
        </View>
      );
    return (
      <AudioContext.Provider
        value={{
          audioFiles,
          dataProvider,
          playbackObj,
          soundObj,
          currentAudio,
          isPlaying,
          currentAudioIndex,
          totalAudioCount: this.totalAudioCount,
          playbackPosition,
          playbackDuration,
          rate,
          updateState: this.updateState,
          loadPreviousAudio: this.loadPreviousAudio,
          onPlaybackStatusUpdate: this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AudioContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}


import {Component} from 'react';
import AsyncStorageLib from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default AudioProvider;
```

and here's some more:

```
// play audio
// Import the react-native-sound module

import { PitchCorrectionQuality,shouldCorrectPitch, rate } from "expo-av/build/AV.types";

export const play = async (playbackObj, uri,) => {
    try {
       return await playbackObj.loadAsync(
        {uri}, 
        {shouldPlay: true},
    );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error inside play helper method', error.message)
    }  
};

//pause
export const pause = async playbackObj => {
    try {
        // playbackObj.setRateAsync(rate = 2.0, shouldCorrectPitch = true, PitchCorrectionQuality= High);
        return await playbackObj.setStatusAsync({
            shouldPlay: false},
            );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error inside pause helper method', error.message)
    }  
};
//resume
export const resume = async playbackObj => {
    try {
        return await playbackObj.playAsync(
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error inside pause resume method', error.message)
    }  
};

//select next 
export const playNext = async (playbackObj, uri) => {
 try {
     await playbackObj.stopAsync()
     await playbackObj.unloadAsync();
     return await play(playbackObj, uri);
 } catch (error) {
     console.log('error inside playNext helper method')
 }
}
```

I've tried including 'rate: 2.0' inside `this.state{audioFiles: []`,
permissionError: false, etc.} but it didn't work.
Also I've tried doing: `await playbackObj.setRateAsync()` in the 2nd code snippet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, I found the solution. Here's my updated code:

```
// play audio
// Import the react-native-sound module

import { PitchCorrectionQuality,shouldCorrectPitch, rate } from "expo-av/build/AV.types";

export const play = async (playbackObj, uri,) => {
    try {
       await playbackObj.loadAsync(
        {uri}, 
        {shouldPlay: true},
    );
    return await playbackObj.setStatusAsync({ rate: 0.9749090909 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error inside play helper method', error.message)
    }  
};

//pause
export const pause = async playbackObj => {
    try {
        return await playbackObj.setStatusAsync({
          shouldPlay: false,
          rate: 0.9749090909,
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error inside pause helper method', error.message)
    }  
};
//resume
export const resume = async playbackObj => {
    try {
        return await playbackObj.playAsync(
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error inside pause resume method', error.message)
    }  
};

//select next 
export const playNext = async (playbackObj, uri) => {
 try {
     await playbackObj.stopAsync()
     await playbackObj.unloadAsync();
     return await play(playbackObj, uri);
 } catch (error) {
     console.log('error inside playNext helper method')
 }
}
```